# Remove empty lines between lines with content

Tags: javascript, regex

I'd like to know if someone can help me with regex on javascript.

So basically I have the following string as an example:

`var str = "A\nB\n\n\nC\n\n\n\n\nD"` and I want to convert it to `"A\nB\n\nC\n\n\n\nD"` using regex or any other way around to do this with javascript.

The idea here is remove only one empty line between lines with content.
Is there any way to do this?

Comment: [`[\r\n]([\r\n]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/MdQ4HN/2)?

Comment: That will find all the break lines in the string, not sure how can I remove only one empty line between lines with content.

Comment: That's exactly what you said you wanted: `I want to convert it to "A\nB\n\nC\n\n\n\nD"`

Comment: i like the trick, and yet done is better this posted solutions, get a good time

Answer (score 3):

One possible approach:

```js
var str = "A\nB\n\n\nC\n\n\n\n\nD"

var out = str.replace(/\n(\n+)/g, '$1')

console.log(out) // "A\nB\n\nC\n\n\n\nD"
```

Comment: That works perfectly, thanks.
Can you please let me know does the $1?

Comment: `$1` refers to the first _capturing group_ `()` of the regex. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) for more info.

Comment: great, this is real control of regex ;)

Answer (score 0):

### Code

As per my comment

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/MdQ4HN/3)

```
[\r\n]([\r\n]+)
```

With using just `\n`.

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/MdQ4HN/4)

```
\n(\n+)
```

Replacement

```
$1
```

#### Usage

```js
const regex = /\n(\n+)/gm;
const str = `A
B


C




D`;
const subst = `$1`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```

---

### Results

#### Input

```
A
B


C




D
```

#### Output

```
A
B

C



D
```

---

#### Explanation

It's matching a `\n`, then capturing all the `\n` that follow it into capture group 1. It then replaces those locations with capture group 1 (`$1`). The result is one less `\n` than before. This will only match 2+ `\n` and will not match a `\n` that is alone.

Comment: You are totally right, I didn't know how to use the $1 that's why I didn't get how your tip could help, but thanks to your explanation it totally makes sense now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [LookAhead](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html). Use when is needed search something but not include this in the result query.

```js
var str = "A\nB\n\n\nC\n\n\n\n\nD"

var resultWithLookAhead = str.replace(/(?=\n)(\n+)/g, "\n")

console.log(resultWithLookAhead);
```

Comment: That's not a lookbehind.

Comment: Also, it removes all line breaks except for one, rather than just one.

Comment: LOL, My fault. Didnt read the last phrase asking for just one line to remove. Solved.